# Description of $C^0$ curve

Tags: continuity, curves

Suppose there is a curve that is already parametrized.

It is called $C^0$ continuity because there is a kink.

There are three places. which are $C^0$ $C^1$ $C^0$ respectively.

Here are the questions.

1. Can we say "it is $C^2$ if we didn't consider those three place"?
2. We have terminology "kink" to say $C^0$ place.
   What is the terminology to say $C^1$ place?

Comment: What's a "place" and what does it mean for it to be $C^k$?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I have data and I use a curve to interpolate this data by connecting data one by one using the line. Then I have the curve, but the curve shows an obvious kink. The curve is drawn in (X,Y) coordinate. The place means (x,y) where the kink occurs.